# Change numbers into ints in a dictionary

Tags: python

```
dic = { 'a': '3','b':'4'}
```

I want this to become this:

```
dic = {'a':3,'b':4}
```

In other words, I want to remove the quotes from the number. I am using Python. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Learn the difference between the various native types in Python. `'3'` and `'4'` aren't numbers, they are strings composed of numeric characters. To get them in the form you want, you must create `int`s, which is easily done from numeric strings using the default `int` constructor (as shown in @JonClements's answer).

Answer (score 10):

Use a dict-comprehension and convert the value to an `int`:

```
dic = {k:int(v) for k,v in dic.iteritems()}
```

If you're not using 2.7+, then you have to use the following:

```
dic = dict( (k, int(v)) for k, v in dic.iteritems() )
```

If you're using >= Py 3, then `iteritems` doesn't exist, so you use:

```
dic = {k:int(v) for k,v in dic.items()}
```

And, before I get another comment, I'll just throw in a universal (in-place) approach of:

```
for key in dic:
    dic[key] = int(dic[key])
```

Comment: @PaulSeeb works in 2.7 as well - but have updated post to reflect prior versions

Comment: @PaulSeeb: actually, that wouldn't work in 3, because of the `.iteritems()` instead of `.items()`. :^)

Comment: @DSM ugh... yep, good point as well - sheesh... Think I've covered bases now!